# How to subscribe to actual view changes in Angular?

Tags: angular

When working with Angular, the change detection runs and checks if some parts of the UI needs to be refresh/re-render.

There's lifecycle hooks, but... I am not able to find an event/hook/observable to listen for view changes.

What do I call view changes ? When Angular finds that there is changes in the model that need to be updated on the view. It can be because of a variable binding, or any expression. When relying on `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook, we are only notified about `@Input` changes. But changes can come from various sources.

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dJTB4B1S4pEKEKk6O9Z0?p=preview) for a basic implementation. You can open the console to see `console.log` in the `ngOnChanges`.

The **Input value** input changes the value passed to the component with `@Input`. The `ngOnChanges` can detect this kind of changes.

The **Service value** input changes a value stocked in some shared service, displayed inside our component. The `ngOnChanges` does not detect this and if we use `OnPush` detection strategy, our component won't see this changes.

But in our case, we don't want to use `OnPush`, and we want to be able to listen to this view change.

In this example, we use a simple input to perform some changes, but in the real world, this can be some async callback...

I look for something generic, provided by the `ViewRef` or something like that, because it can be any `Component`s or `TemplateRef` that perform changes that need to be detected.

### Real use case

I cannot rely on Component inner implementation or service, it has to be Component agnostic. My real use case is to detect changes in a `TemplateRef` attached to a `@angular/cdk` [Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview). I need to be notified about changes, so I can tell the overlay to update its positioning.

**tooltip.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[appTooltip]"
})
export class TooltipDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input("appTooltip") templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

    private _overlayRef: OverlayRef;
    private _portal: TemplatePortal<any>;

    constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private _injector: Injector, private _overlay: Overlay) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._overlayRef = this._overlay.create();
        this._portal = new TemplatePortal(this.templateRef, this._viewContainerRef);
    }

    @HostListener("mouseenter")
    show() {
        this._overlayRef.attach(this._portal);
    }

    @HostListener("mouseleave")
    hide() {
        this._overlayRef.detach();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._overlayRef.dispose();
    }

    /** I need to call this when changes are detected inside the templateRef. */
    onTemplateChange() {
        this._overlayRef.updatePosition();
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-template #myTemplate>
    <h3>Some {{ variable }} bindings</h3>
    <app-custom-component [withInput]="someVariable"></app-custom-component>
    <app-other-component></app-other-component>
</ng-template>

<p>Show tooltip when hover <span [appTooltip]="myTemplate">this</span>.</p>
```

In this example, the `ng-template` element can contain anything the developer wants, and the `TooltipDirective` is not aware of what you can put inside the `ng-template`.

The `CustomComponent` can update its view base on anything you want, and the `ngOnChanges` isn't necessarily called. But its view is updated, so Angular knows it needs to update the template.

Comment: You can use `ngAfterViewChecked`, but this fire every time the component *checks* for changes, whether or not any changes have occurred

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but it is a pity to have to manually check for actual changes.

Comment: Downvote without any comment ?

Comment: Sorry your English isn't the best... Is there some mythical situation in which the DOM will be changing and the component won't know about it?

Comment: The view depends on the model. That's the basic principle. So if the view changes, it means the model changes. So you should wonder how to be aware of changes in the model, not to changes in the view. So, if you want a component to be aware of a value changed in a service, then expose an observable in the service, and emit an event from that observable when the value changes. The component can then subscribe to the observable to know that the value has changed.

Comment: I cannot rely on Component inner implementation or service, it has to be Component agnostic. My real use case is to detect changes in a TemplateRef attached to a @angular/cdk Overlay Portal. I need to be notified about changes, so I can tel the overlay to update its positioning. I have edited my question.

Comment: I took a long look at it and found nothing to make `ngOnChange` respond to changes in the value from the service, even when wrapping that value in a BehaviorSubject and observing it in the component.

Comment: The change detector works fine and keeps the view updated, but sadly `ngOnChanges` is not a log for everything the change detector does.

Comment: The best you could do is to create another service which manages all non-Input property changes (probably via observables) and emits a list you can subscribe to. That way gives you just one more service to inject in the component.